# Show image very slowly ... after page is completely loaded

Tags: jquery

Show image very slowly ... after page is completely loaded....

That is ,

fade in Effect for the image, but this image should show very slowly page load is completed....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you meant onload (all assets have downloaded) and not DOMReady (the page itself is ready to go):

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('img').fadeIn(10000); // 10 seconds
});
```

Code untested. Don't forget to set images to have an opacity of 0 in your CSS when you start.

Comment: > $(window).load(function () {
> $('#book').animate({ height: 'show', opacity: 'show' }, 'slow');  
> 
> });



i tried somthing like this

Answer (score 0):

alternative approach to @Matchu's, still need the css opacity set to 0

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img').show(10000); // 10 seconds
});
```

EDIT: this will also animate the hight and width, in addition to the opacity.

Comment: I don't think `show` and `fadeIn` have the same effect - it depends on which he really wants.

Comment: $(window).load(function () {
$('#book').animate({
    opacity: 5.25,
    left: '+=50',
    height: 'toggle'
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});

with this snippet...but image need to show

Comment: @Matchu: from jquery docs: When a duration is provided, .show() becomes an animation method. The .show() method animates the width, height, and opacity of the matched elements simultaneously.

Comment: Right. `show` animates height and width, as well. `fadeIn` just fades it in.